# Как использовать ip без домена на ispmanger?

Tags: php, apache, ispmanager, isp

Залез тут тестировать vpn с `ispmanager`. Есть ip, а домена нету!
Как можно временно, без домена, пользоваться ip? 
Что бы сайт именно работал на ip адресе, куда был установлен `ispmanager`.

Answer (score 1):

ISPmanager стоит "поверх" apache или nginx. 
поэтому править надо их конфиги.

пример для апача:
надо закоментировать ServerName строчку (поставить # в начале).

[image: редактирование конфигов апача в ISPmanager]